# Multiple Ingress Controllers by IP

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I'd like to have multiple ingress controllers for each IP address. One of them is forwarded by router and have public services, and another one for private local services only. Pseudo configuration is below:

```
- nginx-private:
    externalIPs: ["192.168.1.11"]
- nginx-public:
    externalIPs: ["192.168.1.12"]
```

But when I set `externalIPs` parameter for my Ingress Controller service, it stops answering for requests. What am I do wrong? Values of testing Helm release are these:

```
controller:
  ingressClass: "nginx-private"
  setAsDefaultIngress: true
  service:
    type: "LoadBalancer"
    loadBalancerSourceRanges: # Also tried without these parameter
      - 192.168.1.0/24
    externalIPs:
      - 192.168.1.11
```

BTW I'm using RKE2